# Can i take dump of /proc/pid/exe

Tags: security, linux

One of process invaded my system. I traced that process id, and wanted to dump /proc/pid/exe to that i can investigate  later. Please advice how i take dump of /proc/pid/exe

Answer (score 3):

`/proc/<pid>/exe` is just a symlink to the executable used to start the given process; it is not any kind of magic link to the memory allocate to that process.  You can't meaningfully dump it for future investigation.